# framework does not contain bitcode ... for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire, carthage

I am using macbook air M1 and xcode 14 I try to compile my project with having carthage as dependency manager with dependency Alamofire 4.9.1 . everytime I archive for arm64 devices I get `'/somePath to xcode library/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. file '/some path to /Alamofire.framework/Alamofire' for architecture arm64`
this occurs only when archiving but when I run in simulator it works perfectly with logs coming out .

I tried to search for solutions online and found some answer related to build settings to enable Bitcode and disable bit code tried with both probability didn't worked error persisted

Comment: do you need specifically version 4.9.1 for a reason or...? That version is from Oct 2019. I'd say you should probably try to use the latest and see if the error persists. A version almost 4 years old could fail easily given that there has been some changes "recently" with the bitcode issues, M1 and new arm64 arch for simulators.

Comment: project is already using this version of alamofire and have too many features build on top of it so migrating to newer version is seemingly not possible now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitcode is no longer supported or required by Xcode 14. You need to update your Xcode. If you absolutely must use an older Xcode, you need to update your project settings to disable Bitcode (just search for bitcode in the settings). Depending on how you've integrated the dependencies you may need to set something there as well, like a CocoaPods `post_install` hook.